# Open and connected in normed space implies path-connected

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, path-connected

> Suppose that $V$ is an open subset of a normed space $X$. Then $V$ is connected iff $V$ is path-connected.

**My attempt:**

The implication $\Leftarrow$ is a well-known result. My question is about the other implication:

It suffices to show that every $x\in V$ has a path-connected neighborhood. $V$ is open, so for all $x\in V$ there is a neighborhood $W_x$ of $0$ such that $x+W_x\subseteq V$. I believe that all $W_x$'s are path-connected, since we can take different elements $a,b\in W_x$, find a simple path between $a, 0$ an $b,0$ (of the form $t\mapsto ta$), and by linking these two lines together we can find a path between $a$ and $b$. A normed space is a topological vector space and therefore $x+W_x$ is path-connected for all $x\in V$ (addition is a homeomorphism). Can I conclude the $V$ is path-connected?

Is the above reasoning somewhat in the right direction? Can this be approach in a different way? Maybe by working via path-connected components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof doesn't work if $W_x$ is just some open set containg $x$ because such a set need even be connected.

Fix $x$ and consider the set of all points $y$ such that there is path in $V$ from $x$ to $y$. Since $V$ is connected it is enough to show that this set is both open and closed in $V$. [For the  it is empty of=r equal to $X$. But the set contains $x$ so it cannot be empty].
If a take a point $y$ in this set then there is an open ball $B$ centered at $x$ contained in $V$. Let $z \in B$ There is a path from $x$ to $y$ and there is a path from $y$ to $z$ in $V$, namely $t \to tz+(1-t)y$. Hence there is a path in $V$ from $x$ to $z$. We have proved that the ball $B$ is contained in our set is it is open.

The fact that this set is close is proved in a similar way. (If there is no path from $x$ to $y$ there cannot be any path from $x$ to $x=z$ either!).

What is crucial to this proof is convexity of open balls in an normed linear space.